# Lock Db Asp.Net via ApplicationContext

Tags: asp.net, locking

I got a db where I need to write entries to a table.
I need to make sure that my table will contain only 20 rows at any given time (I'm making it simple).
Of course, since I am in a web app, I have several users at the same time.

This is what I plan to do :

I use an aspx page with a button "AddRecord", when I click on it, I do this :

```
public void click(event e...)
{
    Object lockInstance = ApplicationContext["lockObject"];
    if (lockInstance  == null)
     {
     // Create Object and store it in app context.

     }

    lock(lockInstance)
    {
          // Run Query select count bla bla
          // if count < 20 then insert...
    }

}
```

No triggers, or stored proc (no I'm not biased, the person I'm working for is :) )

Is there a better way than to rely on the Application Context ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution wouldn't work on a web garden or load balanced web farm scenario. I suggest you use proper DB locks.

You can, for example. begin a transaction, execute a select statement using TABLOCKX (which locks the table exclusively), add some rows, if there are less than 20, and finally commit the transaction.

See [locking hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Correct on the non working in web garden or load balanced, I had read it also, thanks for pointing it out though :)